# Django create multi colums flexible best practices

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to create a picture viewer with many colums. I don' know exactly the number.

I want to respect best practices.

I have done the following code :

```
{% with max=4 taille=3 %}
    {% for image in image_list %}
        {% if nb == 1 %}
            <div class="row">
        {% endif %}
            <div class="col-sm-{{ taille }}">
                <a href="{{ image.url }}">{{ image.name }}</a>
            </div>
        {% if nb == 2 %}
            </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% nb += 1 %}
        {% if nb > 4 %}
            {% nb = 1 %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

But the templating system don't allow me to do this line :

```
{% nb += 1 %}
```

Do you have any ideas ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick example on how you can do this (this is for 2 column based itteration) but you can change it to your liking (replace "2" with a integer for instance):

```
<div class="row">
{% for image in image_list %}
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <a href="{{ image.url }}">{{ image.name }}</a>
    </div>
    {% if not forloop.last and forloop.counter|divisibleby:"2" %}
</div>
<div class="row">
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django Templates you can not use += 1 operator 
you can use the forloop.counter

```
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 %}   so every 4 iterations 
                                            starting with first iteration where 
                                            counter is 0
        <div class="row">
    {% endif %}
        <div class="col-sm-{{ taille }}">
            <a href="{{ image.url }}">{{ image.name }}</a>
        </div>
    {% if forloop.counter0|add:"-1"|divisibleby:"4" %}  also every 4 iterations 
                                                       but starting with the 2nd
                                                       iteration where counter is 1
        </div>
    {% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you but Django tells me : Invalid filter: 'divisbleby'. My problem is solved.